# Xamarin Picker inside ListView ItemDisplayBinding Binding: Property not found

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I've a Picker inside a ListView with databinding:

```
          <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding CursorPrintParametersList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CursorPrintParameters">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                      <Picker 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding LabelTypes}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLabelType}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Description}"
                        />

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
```

where `CursorPrintParametersList` is

```
ObservableCollection<CursorPrintParameters> CursorPrintParametersList
```

and

```
public class CursorPrintParameters : INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public List<BaseDto> LabelTypes { get; set; }


    private BaseDto selectedLabelType;
    public BaseDto SelectedLabelType
    {
        get => selectedLabelType;
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;

            selectedLabelType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedLabelType));
        }
    }



}


public class BaseDto
{
    public string Code{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

I'm unable to set the ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Description}" for the Picker, getting a

```
Property 'Description' not found on 'CursorPrintParameters'
```

If i put the picker outside the ListView, everything works fine.
Any help? Thanks

Comment: What's your Xamarin.Forms version,i run it with your codes,and it works. or could you share your project ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT the Xamarin.Forms version is 3.6.0.344457; i cannot update to 4. The project is pretty complex, so it is difficult to share. Thanks

Comment: ok,i will test it on XF 3.6.0.34457 first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i reproduce your issue in Xamarin.Forms version `3.6.0.34457`

and the solution is delete below codes in `DataTemplate` :

```
x:DataType="models:CursorPrintParameters"
```

It is better to upgrade to the latest version if possible, as there may be some API changes

Comment: Though I found the same by me, this is the right solution, so you deserve the accepted answer, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`ItemDisplayBinding` is the name of the property to use for the Display, not an actual binding expression

```
ItemDisplayBinding="Description"
```